# Ui overflow when Keyboard opens in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

In design, I have divided screen in three-part using Expanded but in Second part have a `textfield` when user try to input something the design overflows by some pixel, I have been trying to use `SingleChildScrollView` inside Expanded with container widget to get rid of the rendering problem but my design disappears.

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: _buildBackground(),
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 13,
                //child:_toolBar('VENUE LOGIN')
                child:MyWidget(headerText: 'Player Option',)
              ),
             Expanded(
                flex: 70,
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: width*0.03),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent),child: PlayerOptionContainer(),),
              ),

              Expanded(
                flex: 17,
                child: _bottomView1(width),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

PlayerOptionWidget method

```
 Widget PlayerOptionContainer(){
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(flex:25,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(flex: 30,child: _logoContainer(width),),
                Expanded(flex: 70,child:  searchContainer(),),

            ],),),
          Expanded(flex:75,child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent),
            child: GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              children: List.generate(20, (index) {
                return Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width*0.02, bottom: width*0.02, right: width*0.02),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: MyColors.yellowBg,
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                  ),
                  child: Center(child: MyFeedTile(),),
                );
              }),
            ),
           ),)],
      );
    }
```

This is the design trying to achieve

[image]

But it gets overflow by some pixel

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Common problem. There are a couple solutions

1. You can wrap body (`Stack`) in `SingleChildScrollView`
2. You can try `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` parameter of `Scaffold`:

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, ... )
```